# Visual Studio C++ не подсвечивает ошибки

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Я не знаю баг это или фича, но Visual Studio C++ (VS 141) не подсвечивает ошибки если функция использует шаблонные параметры, да и вообще работает с шаблонном. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что с этим делать и как можно решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliSense вполне сносно работает с шаблонами. В VS 2019 в этом плане наблюдается прогресс. Однако многие категории ошибок в шаблонах становятся ошибками только после инстанцирования шаблона или их затруднительно обнаруживать без инстанцирования. Для такого случая в IntelliSense есть возможность предоставлять подсказки для конкретных параметров. Их можно задать кликнув на иконку `<T>` после объявления шаблона.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[C++ team blog Announcing Template IntelliSense](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/template-intellisense/)

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio и не обязано "подсвечивать" ошибки. Функциональность IntelliSense предназначена для беглого поверхностного анализа кода и надежно обнаруживать ошибки не может. Тем более в шаблонном коде. Этого от IntelliSense никто и не ожидает и никакой проблемы тут нет.

Ошибки вам будет рапортовать компилятор, когда вы выполните компиляцию вашего кода.